# Can I create a read-only user in Google Cloud SQL

Tags: google-cloud-sql

Google Cloud SQL only allows you to control the database root user password.
I need to create a new user and limit his access to read-only, while maintaining the full privileged user.

Is there a way of doing that ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 6):

Steps within GCP:

First create database user `username` using `Built-in authentication` option at https://console.cloud.google.com/sql/instances/YOUR_INSTANCE_NAME/users

Then revoke `cloudsqlsuperuser` privilege:

```sql
REVOKE `cloudsqlsuperuser`@`%` FROM `username`@`%`;
```

Grant `SELECT` privilege:

```sql
GRANT SELECT ON *.* TO `username`@`%`;
```

Verify:

```sql
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'USER_NAME';
-- You should see:
-- GRANT SELECT ON *.* TO `username`@`%`
```

Comment: Thank you @Mauricio. Could you please explain what the "\`" and "@" mean? I replaced % with the user I created and using REVOKE and I am getting a syntax error. Let's say the user is called `app_ro` and the db called `app_staging`. How would your syntax work?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that using the regular MySQL permissions. Here is how you can add a user that has SELECT access to a database `test`.

```
mysql> GRANT ALL ON test.* TO user@'%';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.07 sec)

mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR user@'%'\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
Grants for user@%: GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'user'@'%'
*************************** 2. row ***************************
Grants for user@%: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `test`.* TO 'user'@'%'
2 rows in set (0.07 sec)

mysql>
```

If you want to grant SELECT access to all the databases you can use `` GRANT ALL ON `%`.* ``.

Reference: [Cloud SQL: How can I use GRANT ALL?](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/faq#grantall)

Comment: This is not a read only user.

Answer (score 1):

Should not use ALL

```
GRANT SELECT ON test.* TO user@'%';
```

Comment: Check assigned roles/permissions with `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'user'`. You should see something like `GRANT SELECT ON *.* TO \`user\`@\`%\``.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there are three read-write databases, `db_dev`,`db_qa` and `db_prod` and two readonly databases, `readonly_db1` and `readonly_db2`.

I configure the DB account `username@'<IP or %>'` below:

1. Grant privilege

```sql
GRANT ALL ON db_dev.* TO username@'<IP or %>';
GRANT ALL ON db_qa.* TO username@'<IP or %>';
GRANT ALL ON db_prod.* TO username@'<IP or %>';
GRANT SELECT ON readonly_db1.* TO username@'<IP or %>';
GRANT SELECT ON readonly_db2.* TO username@'<IP or %>';
SHOW GRANTS FOR username@'<IP or %>';
```

2. Revoke superuser privilege.

```sql
REVOKE `cloudsqlsuperuser`@`%` FROM username@'<IP or %>';
SHOW GRANTS FOR username@'<IP or %>';
```

The `GRANT` operation must execute before `REVOKE`.